# Laravel queue mail not updating even after queue:restart

Tags: php, linux, laravel, queue

I am sending queued mail with Laravel. the driver is database. I did not install supervisor since it's a shared hosting.

I have updated the blade file of the mail, but even after running `php artisan queue:restart`,  the mail sent is still using the old view.

I have cleared all the cache with `php artisan optimize:clear` or even with `sudo php artisan optimize:clear`.

Interesting thing I can't find there is worker running. No console is running `queue:work`. When I run `ps aux | grep -i 'queue'`, I can't find any process. But the job in my job table is still ran and sent. When I run `queue:listen`, the mail sent is the correct updated one.

Previously, I have used schedule `$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();` before to make sure the queue is live. But the schedule is now stopped.

Is there a hidden queue worker running? and how do I update that queue?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a queue worker running, it's possible that Laravel is using a different method to process the queued jobs. In your case, since you're using the database driver for queues, Laravel can use the **queue:listen** command to process the queued jobs. The **queue:listen** command continuously polls the database for new jobs and processes them as they become available.

Run the following command to start listening for queued jobs:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Reference document: [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues)

Comment: Thanks. When I open a console and run queue:listen, the mail sent is the correct updated one. But when I close this console, the mail will be sent as the old one again. I really don't know where the old mail is stored and what sent it. I even restart the server but no hope